# merge sorting of 2 unsorted arrays

Tags: java, sorting

is the following implemetation correct for merge sort?

```
public int [] merge_srt(int [] ary){
        if(ary.length==1)
            return ary;
        int mid = (int)ary.length/2;
        int a1[] =  merge_srt(Arrays.copyOfRange(ary, 0, mid));
        int a2[] = merge_srt(Arrays.copyOfRange(ary, mid+1,  ary.length-1));
        return mergeA(a1,a2);

    }

    public  int[]  mergeA(int[] a1,int [] a2){

        // merge 2 array and reurn one sorted array

    }
```

Comment: At first glance it seems okay, but what do your tests say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    if (ary.length == 1)            
       return ary;
```

to

```
    if (ary.length <= 1)            
       return ary;
```